Save a macro enabled workbook based on 3 cell values
I am trying to add a code to save a workbook based on 3 cell values. A little background, we have a planner at work that we need to make daily backup, or copies as needed without altering the original copy of the workbook. I have tried several codes but, not having much luck.
Cell A2 example "05-2024"
Cell B2 example "Planner"
Cell C2 is a timestamp =NOW()  *The date and time format is custom to display mm-dd hhmm or 05-08 1200
Sub SaveWorkbookAsXlsm()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    folderPath = "C:\Art\"
    fileName = wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value & "_" & _
               wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value & "_" & _
               wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value & ".xlsm"
    wb.SaveAs fileName:=folderPath & fileName, FileFormat:=52
End Sub

Is there a better way?
I tried the above code, it did not work. I am trying to save the workbook based on cells A2, B2 & C2. When we begin a new month we create a copy of our planner and basically name it for example 05-2024 Planner. We need to make backup saves periodically with the date and time. I am trying to code the worbook to save based on the cell values to simplify the process.

Use Format$ if you want to have the date and time format.

Do you have a few examples of the cell values and what the expected names should be and what the issue is? "It did not work" doesn't necessarily clarify the issue.

Use Range("C2").Text if you want the formatted/displayed value from that cell.   Add Debug.print filename to make sure you're getting what you expect.


Using SaveCopyAs saves a copy of the workbook to a file but doesn't modify the open workbook in memory. SaveAs is a different method. It will change the workbook in Excel.

Microsoft documentation:

Workbook.SaveCopyAs method (Excel)


Workbook.SaveAs method (Excel)


The timestamp can be created on the fly (modify time formatting as needed). Cell C1 is not necessary.

Sub SaveWorkbookAsXlsm()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    folderPath = "C:\Art\"
    With wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        fileName = .Range("A2").Value & "_" & _
                   .Range("B2").Value & "_" & _
                   Format(Now(), "mm-dd hhmmss") & ".xlsm"
    End With
    wb.SaveCopyAs FileName:=folderPath & fileName
End Sub


If the filename (A1&B1) of backup copy is same as the main workbook, the code can be simplified as below. Cells A1 & B1 are not necessary too.

Sub SaveWorkbookAsXlsm()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim folderPath As String, aFile
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    folderPath = "C:\Art\"
    aFile = Split(wb.Name, ".")
    If UBound(aFile) = 0 Then ' new created workbook
        MsgBox "Please save the active workbook before run the code."
    Else
        aFile(UBound(aFile) - 1) = aFile(UBound(aFile) - 1) & "_" & Format(Now(), "mm-dd hhmmss")
        fileName = Join(aFile, ".")
        Debug.Print fileName ' validate the filename (for testing)
        wb.SaveCopyAs fileName:=folderPath & Join(aFile, ".")
    End If
End Sub


Thank you for the assistance and I apologize for the slow response.
